# Правильно будет обернуть svg в текстовый тег span?

Tags: html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, с точки зрения семантики `Html`, правильно будет `svg` иконку оборачивать в `span`?

Очень часто бывает что иконка расположена рядом с текстом и возникает соблазн вложить `svg` в тег `span`

Вот пример, c использованием `tailwind`, `react` и `ts`.
Я уверен, опытный разработчик суть уловил, даже если он и не работает с этими технологиями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще есть такое понятие как блочный и строчный элемент(думаю вы и так это знаете). Я к тому, что в зависимости от конечного результата, тег может использоваться любой и по разным причинам, с разными правилами. Так вот span - строчный элемент, и не зря был таким придуман, ведь правда?

Поэтому мне кажется разумнее использовать сразу `DIV`, но если ваши причины сильнее "стандартов"(или что-то вроде того), то легко можно диктовать `span'y` свои правила по типу:

```
span{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Но зачем?
Да и код приведенный вами, мне абсолютно не знаком, но как я его вижу с высоты своей башни(мааааленькой такой, но башни) :

```
<div class='className'>
    <!-- img взята исключительно для наглядности, тк можно описать класс "className" и сделать отличную иконку с текстом, или текст с иконкой как удобно -->
    <img src = 'icon'>
    <span>TEXT - icon</span>
</div>
```

Итог? `span` - как использовался для текста, так и используется.

Говоря о span'e как о внутреннем теге - тега - Button,
если мой `.html`:

```
    <button type="button">
        <span>M</span>y button
    </button>
```

То например в `.css`:

```
span{
    color: red;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подобные манипуляции я очень люблю использовать именно со `span'om`. И если исходить из данного контекста - то почему бы ему с легкостью не стать блочным, и не хранить в себе даже картинку? Но зачем? Опять же, что-то мне подсказывает, что я возможно гляжу сквозь пальцы и не могу уловить суть задачи.

```css
button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

svg{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
        <svg width="14" height="14">
            <circle cx="7" cy="7" r="5" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
        
          Hello
    </button>
```

Очередной вопрос. Зачем `SPAN` - как блок в коде? Если `SVG` - и есть блок(контейнер)? Следуя из этой мысли, я без вспомогательных блоков могу управлять поведением `SVG` - тегом :)

Comment: В рамках текущего вопроса я думаю ответ более чем точный.

Но мне хочется пойти дальше, так как в моем проекте, этот компонент вкладывается в строчно-блочный элемент Button.

Такие элементы являются встроенным, но для них можно задавать поля, отступы, ширину и высоту.

Как в таком кейсе лучше поступить?

Я предполагаю, что надо обертке-div задать display: inline-block;

Но я не уверен что можно вкладывать друг в друга строчно-блочные элемент.


Что вы на это скажите?

Comment: Если правильно понял, то поместить в тег button > span вполне себе разумное решение, для манипуляции с конкретным участком текста например. О чем я? Ответ дополню

Comment: button => span => (svg & span => text)